# Dockerfile Django not opening in browser

Tags: django, docker

I'm using **Django 2.x** and dockerizing the application.

I have the following **Dockerfile** content.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Install Rabbit-mq server
RUN echo @testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk --update add \
 libxml2-dev \
 libxslt-dev \
 libffi-dev \
 gcc \
 musl-dev \
 libgcc curl \
 jpeg-dev \
 zlib-dev \
 freetype-dev \
 lcms2-dev \
 openjpeg-dev \
 tiff-dev \
 tk-dev \
 tcl-dev \
 mariadb-connector-c-dev \
 supervisor \
 nginx \
 --no-cache bash

# Set environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set locale variables
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# -- Install Application into container:
RUN set -ex && mkdir /app

# -- Adding dependencies:
ADD . /app/

# Copy environment variable file
ADD src/production.env /app/src/.env


COPY scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh /app/

# Switch to the working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod ug+x /app/entrypoint.sh

# Install Pipenv first to use pipenv module
RUN pip install pipenv

# -- Adding Pipfiles
ONBUILD COPY Pipfile Pipfile
ONBUILD COPY Pipfile.lock Pipfile.lock
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy

RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor.d
COPY configs/docker/supervisor/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini

EXPOSE 80 8000

CMD ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and the **entrypoint.sh** hash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec gunicorn --pythonpath src qcg.wsgi:application -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -t 300 --max-requests=100
```

I use the command to build the image

```
docker build . -t qcg_new
```

and running it using

```
docker run qcg_new
```

It runs the docker and the gunicorn server is also running on `8000` port

```
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2019-09-16 09:03:31 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

But when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `http://localhost:8000` in the browser, it does not opens.

Comment: did you puplish the port in your docer run command ?

Comment: why publish if `expose` is there in the **Dockerfile**?

Comment: because the expose in Dockerfile is only for doumentation purposes

Comment: A Dockerfile in general isn't allowed to specify that some host resource will get used.  The operator could pick a different port or choose not to publish the port at all.  The `docker run -p` option is pretty much required here.

Comment: As mentioned by @davi you should expose port, but if you insist not to publish port and still want to access the container. then run `docker inspect container_name ` copy the `IP:8000` and paste it in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

see it [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

so you need to `-p 8000:8000` in your run command

Comment: Still same issue after running `docker run qcg_new -p 8000:8000`

Comment: Thanks. Running after switching image position to last. `docker run -p 8000:8000 qcg_new`